# Value input type number

Tags: javascript

If I have few   on my form. How can I access to input what I need?

```
    <label> First </label>
    <input type="number" value="1" min="1">
    <label>22</label>
    <span>There I need value in input * val in label</span>

    <label> Second </label>
    <input type="number" value="1" min="1">
    <label>12</label>
    <span>There I need value in input * val in label</span>
................................
```

How can I do this? Maybe I need to use loop?

Comment: Give your `<input>` an ID or class and use the `for` attribute on your `<label>`?

Comment: Can you use jquery? Or just pure javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly which `input` you are trying to access. 
You can use `document.querySelectorAll("input[type=number]").`

It will return an array with all inputs of type "number". Iterate through them to get what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `id` to the controls and then access it using jquery by the id.

```
<label> First </label>
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" id="input1">
<label id="label1">22</label>
<span id="span1">There I need value in input * val in label</span>

<label> Second </label>
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" id="input2">
<label id="label2">12</label>
<span id="span2">There I need value in input * val in label</span>
```

Then on your `dcoument.ready` just calculate it like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var result1=$(#input1).val()*$(#label1).val();
$('#span1').val(result1);

var result2=$(#input2).val()*$(#label2).val();
$('#span1').val(result2);
});
```

After you gave an `id` to the controls you can do it even nicer, looping through all the inputs an dynamically multiply them:

```
    var i=0;
    $("#myForm input[type=text]").each(function() {
        i=i+1;
        $('#span'+i).val($('#input'+i)*('#label'+i));            
    });
```

Comment: jQuery is not a tag for this question, which makes this answer - focused as it is purely on a jQuery solution - a non-answer to the posted question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` loop to loop all inputs and `addEventListener` to run function on input change. Then just calculate value for each input and add to `span` as `textContent`.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    var val = this.value * Number(this.nextElementSibling.textContent);
    this.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.textContent = val;
  })
}
```

```html
<label>First</label>
<input type="number" value="1" min="1">
<label>22</label>
<span>There I need value in input * val in label</span>

<label>Second</label>
<input type="number" value="1" min="1">
<label>12</label>
<span>There I need value in input * val in label</span>
```

If you want to add values to spans even before input change you can add this part of code to previous one.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  var val = inputs[i].value * Number(inputs[i].nextElementSibling.textContent);
  inputs[i].nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.textContent = val;

  inputs[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    var val = this.value * Number(this.nextElementSibling.textContent);
    this.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.textContent = val;
  })
}
```

```html
<label>First</label>
<input type="number" value="1" min="1">
<label>22</label>
<span>There I need value in input * val in label</span>

<label>Second</label>
<input type="number" value="1" min="1">
<label>12</label>
<span>There I need value in input * val in label</span>
```